# Laravel 7- "Undefined index: email", when trying to send email

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send email using Laravel, but I am getting the error message

`"Undefined index: email"`

**Here is my code**

```
public function contact_us(Request $request){
  $cu_full_name = $request->cu_full_name;
  $cu_email     = $request->cu_email;
  $cu_message   = $request->cu_message;
  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
  $cu_received_dt         =   date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ");

$data= array([
    'name'=>$cu_full_name,
    'email'=> $cu_email,
    'message'=>$cu_message
]);

  

  Mail::send('emails.home',$data,function ($message) use($data){
   $message->from('example@example.com');
   $message->to($data['email'])->subject('New Message Received.'); **<-error message for this line**
});

//Other codes
```

Comment: your $data shows as ARRAY.. you cannot access like $data['email'].. whether you remove the array or use $data[0]['email]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you wrapping array inside array ?
try to define `data` like that  :

```
$data= [
    'name'=>$cu_full_name,
    'email'=> $cu_email,
    'message'=>$cu_message
];
```

Or,

```
$data= array(
    'name'=> $cu_full_name,
    'email'=> $cu_email,
    'message'=> $cu_message
);
```

Comment: I was using the previous one, and it was working earlier.

Comment: example `return response()->json(['success'=>true,
        'message'=>"Message received"]); `   --> How does this works  and the above one(in my question) does not?